# Can't create cookies/sessions in Laravel 4.2

Tags: php, session, cookies, laravel

Out of nowhere, my **Laravel (4.2)** app stopped creating cookies (therefore, it stopped to link sessions with those cookies). I'm running this test that I saw in another post:

```
// routes.php

Route::get('cookieset', function(){
    $cookie = Cookie::make('foo', 'bar', 60);
    return Redirect::to('cookieget')->withCookie($cookie);
});

Route::get('cookieget', function(){
    dd(Cookie::get('foo'));
});
```

So if I open **/cookieset** in the browser, the cookie itself gets created (It is posible to **dd($cookie)** before the **Reditect::to()**. I get this result:

```
 object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Cookie)#165 (7) {
     ["name":protected]=> string(3) "foo"
     ["value":protected]=> string(3) "bar"
     ["domain":protected]=> NULL
     ["expire":protected]=> int(1409694104)
     ["path":protected]=> string(1) "/"
     ["secure":protected]=> bool(false)
     ["httpOnly":protected]=> bool(true)
 }
```

However, when redirected to **/cookieget**, I got a **NULL** result.

The browser (Google Chrome) dosen't have any "foo" cookies.

I have tried this same code in other Laravel projects and works fine. I don't remember changing anything that could break the framework. I also updated the framework (to 4.2.8) and I get the same result.

I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

**SOLVED:** Apparently, my routes.php file was the issue. It might had some "strange" white character somewhere, so the cookies (therefore the session) never got created. I just created a new routes.php file and everything works fine now.